# Parser issues with custom Lexer

Tags: c++, rdbms, lexer, parser-generator

I am seeking assistance regarding a custom built Lexer class and using it to parse through inputs. Our professor has provided us with some skeleton code for our project, and we MUST use it. 
My issue is this, we need to be able to call multiple functions at once to sort tables and merge/sort columns of separate tables. For instance, our input would be something like:

> display <'file_name> sortedby <'column2>

where 'display' and 'sortedby' are sort of keywords and column2 would be sorted numerically or alphabetically - depending on the content.

We are given the algorithm to use for sorting and my current issue is not with the implementation of that, but with being able to have our Lexer/Parser read more than one input. 
Currently, I can only get the 'display ' bit to work. Anything more just spits back an error message.

I've looked through the code, tried changing some of the logic - switching statements from true to false, swaping &&'s and ||'s, even tried some if-else statements with no luck.

I could really use some advice! Some of the code we are give, in it's original format:

Lexer.h:

```
#ifndef _LEXER_H
#define _LEXER_H
#include <string>

enum token_types_t { 
IDENT,  // a sequence of alphanumeric characters and _, starting with alpha
TAG, // sequence of characters between < >, no escape
ENDTOK, // end of string/file, no more token
ERRTOK  // unrecognized token
};

struct Token {
token_types_t type;
std::string value;
// constructor for Token
Token(token_types_t tt=ENDTOK, std::string val="") : type(tt), value(val) {}
};

class Lexer {
public:
// constructor
Lexer(std::string str="") : input_str(str), cur_pos(0), in_err(false), 
    separators(" \t\n\r") { }

//modifiers 
void set_input(std::string); // set a new input, 
void restart();              // move cursor to the beginning, restart

Token next_token();    // returns the next token
bool has_more_token(); // are there more token(s)?

private:
std::string input_str;  // the input string to be scanned
size_t      cur_pos;    // current position in the input string
bool        in_err;     // are we in the error state?
std::string separators; // set of separators; *not* the best option!
};
#endif
```

Lexer.cpp:

```
#include "Lexer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Token Lexer::next_token() {
Token ret;
size_t last;

if (in_err) {
    ret.type = ERRTOK;
    ret.value = "";
    return ret;
}

// if not in error state, the default token is the ENDTOK
ret.type = ENDTOK;
ret.value = "";

if (has_more_token()) {
    last = cur_pos; // input_str[last] is a non-space char
    if (input_str[cur_pos] == '<') {
        cur_pos++;
        while (cur_pos < input_str.length() && input_str[cur_pos] != '>')
            cur_pos++;
        if (cur_pos < input_str.length()) {
            ret.type = TAG;
            ret.value = input_str.substr(last+1, cur_pos-last-1);
            cur_pos++; // move past the closing "
        } else {
            in_err = true;
            ret.type = ERRTOK;
            ret.value = "";
        }
    } else {
        while (cur_pos < input_str.length() &&
               separators.find(input_str[cur_pos]) == string::npos &&
               input_str[cur_pos] != '<') {
            cur_pos++;
        }
        ret.type  = IDENT;
        ret.value = input_str.substr(last, cur_pos-last);
    }
}
return ret;
}

void Lexer::set_input(string str) {
input_str = str;
restart();
}

bool Lexer::has_more_token() {
while (cur_pos < input_str.length() && 
       separators.find(input_str[cur_pos]) != string::npos) {
    cur_pos++;
}
return (cur_pos < input_str.length());
}

void Lexer::restart() {
cur_pos = 0;
in_err = false;
}
```

Our Parser (part of a bigger .cpp file):

```
bool parse_input(Lexer lexer, string& file_name) {    
Token file_name_tok;

if (!lexer.has_more_token() || 
    (file_name_tok = lexer.next_token()).type != TAG)
    return false;

if  (lexer.has_more_token())
    return false;

file_name = file_name_tok.value;
return true;
}
```

Display function (part of same .cpp file as the parser):

```
void display(Lexer cmd_lexer) {
string file_name, line;

if (!parse_input(cmd_lexer, file_name)) {
    error_return("Syntax error: display <filename>");
    return;
}

ifstream ifs(file_name.c_str());
string error_msg;
if (ifs) {
       if (!is_well_formed(ifs, error_msg)) {
        error_return(error_msg);
    } else {
            ifs.clear();           
        ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg); 
        print_well_formed_file(ifs);
    }
    while (ifs.good()) {
  getline (ifs, line);
  cout << line << endl;
}

} else {
    error_return("Can't open " + file_name + " for reading");
}
ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: Should the `display` "command" read a sourcefile or some other special file?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the answer to my comment, these are the way I would solve the problem:

- If the `display` command should read a source file and parse it, you could implement it though a stack. Whenever the `display` directive is found and parsed, you push a new lexer instance on the stack. Use the top of the stack for the "current" lexer.
- If the `display` command should read and perform some operation on a file unrelated to the actual parsing, then consider storing the instructions in a fixed-form intermediate form, and when done parsing you "execute" this intermediate format. This is the way that almost *all* modern script languages does it.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. We are using files that are in the same directory as the all the source code - so for now we do not need to create or access new files.

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough. To read more than one input you need more than one Lexer/Parser. Just create one for each input you have to read.